# Sound has crashed on my system

Tags: sound

I was listening to music on my laptop; suddenly sound stopped coming ; tried restarting the laptop several times. Sound is still not working; please suggest what to do.

Player: I have tried: rhythm player; smplayer and vlc.

Ubuntu version: 12.04 lts

Comment: Please add details such as the Ubuntu version and the music player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sound settings, check what device is selected in 'Play sound through'. It should be 'Built-in Audio' and nothing like 'HDMI sound', etc.

If it is, change the default output device to 'Built-in Audio' and restart.

Comment: hi, the selected device is 'built-in-speakers'.  yesterday voice from both the speakers stopped coming; today I can hear sound from right speaker but not from left speaker. Please help.

Comment: I'm sorry buddy, but then I have no idea what's wrong. Sounds like a hardware problem to me now.

But wait for some of the more experienced members just in case.

Comment: My system information is as on the following link:-  http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=c01fb83cad333c8039764830fc465fc568abe756

Comment: Somebody please help; still facing the issue.

Comment: This url (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1816616) describes the same problem i am having ; though my left speaker isn't working.  I have also tried with a live cd 'try ubuntu without install' option; the same problem persists. Just want to make sure if this is a hardware issue or is it related to ubuntu so that i can contact the h/w vendor or try reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Any suggestions please? I don't want to go back to windows

Comment: hi, this was a hardware issue, so closing the case.